# tokenfield with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using [Bootstrap tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) with [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). But the list is not displaying any thing except blank fields.

This is my code:

```
$('#country').tokenfield({
   autocomplete: {
      source: "/country", minLength: 1
   },
   showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});
```

Source is returning appropriate data but the autocomplete suggestion is blank.

Is there any fix for this or am i missing something in my code? Please help me with this.

Data returned from source(when I type `ind`):-

```
[
   {"id":"1","dat":"India"},   
   {"id":"2","dat":"Indonesia"}              
]
```

Thanks

Comment: empty or response number blank entries, is your source is returning the data is correct format expected by the auto complete

Comment: ya @Raj the source is returning data in correct format. I edited the question and added the returned data. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data returned should be of this format

```
[
   {"value":"1","label":"India"},   
   {"value":"2","label":"Indonesia"}              
]
```